# CURL Ajax - XML Response - Charset

Tags: php, ajax, curl, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest

I'm about to scrape a Website with several Tabs. Up on each Tab click an AJAX-Request gets send to their server returning the data of the Tab which will be displayed.

Since I need to fetch those Data I checked the HTTP-Requests and manipulated the Header with "hurl.it"(website) to check the response.
I'm receiving the correct results but when i set up my Curl Session with the same Header the response is not the same/readable.

With the Live HTTP Headers Add On I was able to extract the AJAX - URL

**Request** 
POST http://xxxx.xxx.xx/Organisation/AjaxScopeQualification/0e69a479-63e3-4d64-9340-f2e9cc8d84df?tabIndex=3

**HEADERS**
Content-Type: application/xml
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://xxxx.xxx.xx/Organisation/Details/41283

**Response via hurl.it** 
 200 OK       646 bytes       547 ms

HEADERS

Cache-Control: private 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 382 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 01:36:42 GMT 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
Set-Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=fsbx3gX1CykkKL2OIvPFH9GcPj97KEPkK-6WVTA24eI87k0F3gjpt0fyVA2P90S8heeaoqjUps9-UFtzgm8mRAiPqnbS50kytk_NY5K4yHPwa-5l0kCqNzPAo0yjBsPmbisbg3N7P7h6Oz5EdRaN8Fkr0y3G6wdIILI8yMQBj1S1X4GULf9rpQ8IvvSo13KB0; expires=Fri, 29-Jan-2016 03:36:42 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly 
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319 
X-Aspnetmvc-Version: 3.0 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
BODY

{"data":[
{"Id":"9fe29051-31e6-4bfa-a2f1-194d70c0aab9","NrtId":"930ec525-2199-44a9-bc27-c1b28524c9bf","RtoId":"0e69a479-63e3-4d64-9340-f2e9cc8d84df","TrainingComponentType":2,"Code":"TLI41210","Title":"Certificate IV in Transport and Logistics (Road Transport - Car Driving Instruction)","IsImplicit":false,"ExtentId":"01","Extent":"Deliver and assess","StartDate":new Date(2011,11,7,0,0,0),"EndDate":new Date(2016,11,6,0,0,0),"DeliveryNsw":true,"DeliveryVic":true,"DeliveryQld":true,"DeliverySa":true,"DeliveryWa":true,"DeliveryTas":true,"DeliveryNt":true,"DeliveryAct":true,"ScopeDecisionType":0,"ScopeDecision":"Deliver and assess"}],"total":1}

**Response from CURL - var_dump() **
string(382) "�m��j�0�_E蔀����|+�=�B�Kz(=��q8���ICȻWζiq�t��������{ ����y�r;��r�D���@��P���t����Ǚ.�Z������ZaX�;�N�z����~(�[Jor��������7F��H1h������E~�!����aJ#��'䭮�>���Mg�Vr��Ǚ��ȊK�S��A��&݇L�evu���Sl3;�ᱴd]�4�pR�.�]��1�@�`�X��?��ty����p�8����1�R=�t(S�6�[�+-����Vr9��#���f�4���������2#�Ew��їѯ�    ���r��FGZ�O��\���.䲰�7���f^�W���[��;Z���"

Is that a charset problem or am I setting my Curl Options wrong?

**CURL**

```
$url = http://xxxx.xxx.xx/Organisation/AjaxDetailsLoadScope/e11d03e7-37e7-49e8-be54-0bed8eb1c247?_=1454029562507&tabIndex=3
$header = array(
        'Accept: */*',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Length: 0',
        'Content-Type: application/xml',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        "Referer: http://xxxx.xxx.xx/Organisation/Details/$this->code"
    );

//.. 
//$header and $url are saved in arrays and then passed to curlMulti()

function curlMulti($urls, $headers = false) {
    $mh = curl_multi_init(); 
    // For each of the URLs in array
    foreach ($urls as $id => $d) {
        $ch[$id] = curl_init();
        $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;

        if (is_array($headers) && $headers[$id] != false) {
            curl_setopt($ch[$id], CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch[$id], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers[$id]);
        }


        curl_setopt($ch[$id], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$id]); 
    }
    $running = NULL; // Set $running to NULL
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running > 0); // While $running is greater than zero

    foreach ($ch as $id => $content) {
        $results[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($content); 
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $content);  
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh); 
    return $results; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing a little bit around with the Headers and got it working now..

had to delete **'Accept: */*',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'** in the header

```
$header = array(
    'Content-Length: 0',
    'Content-Type: application/xml',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    "Referer: http://xxxx.xxx.xx/Organisation/Details/$this->code"
);
```

works like a charm:

```
stdClass Object
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 9fe29051-31e6-4bfa-a2f1-194d70c0aab9
                [NrtId] => 930ec525-2199-44a9-bc27-c1b28524c9bf
                [RtoId] => 0e69a479-63e3-4d64-9340-f2e9cc8d84df
                [TrainingComponentType] => 2
                [Code] => TLI41210
                [Title] => Certificate IV in Transport and Logistics (Road Transport - Car Driving Instruction)
                [IsImplicit] => 
                [ExtentId] => 01
                [Extent] => Deliver and assess
                [DeliveryNsw] => 1
                [DeliveryVic] => 1
                [DeliveryQld] => 1
                [DeliverySa] => 1
                [DeliveryWa] => 1
                [DeliveryTas] => 1
                [DeliveryNt] => 1
                [DeliveryAct] => 1
                [ScopeDecisionType] => 0
                [ScopeDecision] => Deliver and assess
            )

    )

[total] => 1
)
```